# How can i double spend from my unconfirmed transaction for more than 5 days

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I deposited 0.042105059 BTC from my bitcoin account (1KDcKTBTLWnLUED6yMA4Huj5CfzgKfuvJF) to Livecoin.net account.
(1DaHJ3ewQ3XBDxTLFQ4U9E9C4z8w9uEvGW) about 5 days ago but it is still unconfirmed in blockcain.
The transaction has 0/3 confirmations in blockchain and still pending.
https://blockchain.info/tx/4e19db9b29df ... 756396858c
I learned that it because of lower fee. How can cancel or double my coins.
Could any miner here push my transaction for me.

Comment: Which wallet are you using? The bitcoin-core wallet has a couple of options to either zap mempool transactions or increase the fee on an existing transaction.

Comment: Bitcoin wallet from blockchain

Comment: How can i increase the fee on the existing transaction?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that wallet. On the Bitcoin core wallet you can right click a transaction and choose "Increase transaction fee". To do that the transaction must have had the "Replace by fee" checkbox ticked when it was created.

Comment: You mean you are familiar with Blockchain.info bitcoin wallet. please help me with how to double spend my bitcoin in blockchain.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. You could try child-pays-for-parent.

Your unconfirmed transaction with the txid `4e19db9b29dffd508073dd5d67ad8096559e28ef92da0eeb28fe85756396858c` has two ouputs.
I guess `1CfSS3Q6UxCinGg82gzwm1M6LfaxUFUJh8` (value 0.05739491) is your change output...
You can use that change output as an input for a new transaction where you pay a high fee. Miners will then be interested to mine that new transaction but they can only if they also mine the old one (txid above).

You may use 2x the recommended

### 2. Double-Spend (harder)

- Use `-zapwallettxes=1` as Bitcoin Core startup argument.
- Use CoinControl (enable it via Bitcoin-Qt settings)
- Select your "blocked" input (`1KDcKTBTLWnLUED6yMA4Huj5CfzgKfuvJF` from `7aa1366669c3c836d7bf7abbc9b934af62bf669a250b66ccd2d72197aeafee35` 0.0995BTC) in CoinControl and do a new transaction

Comment: Please show me steps to go about the child-pays-for parent.I try the this process how to execute the double-spend operation that @FlyButterfly described: https://bitzuma.com/posts/how-to-clear- ... ansaction/ but the last process says "64: scriptsig-not-pushonly". what does it mean?

Comment: `zapwallettxes` has been removed